# Enum To SelectList MarkCurrentAsSelected Value Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have code like this:

```
model.Availables = enmAvailability.Ava1.ToSelectList(false).ToList();
model.Availables.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "All", Value = "-1", Selected = true });
```

In this condition, in the drop down list it should select "All", but "Ava1" comes as selected. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Post please your cshtml code for dopdown.

Comment: Because the property your binding to has a value of `Ava1` (that is how model binding works - it binds to the value of your property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Value of Ava1 is "0", btw. And it's increasing 1 by 1.

Comment: @CristianSzpisjak @Html.DropDownList("SearchAvailables", Model.Availables)

Comment: Then that means the value of `SearchAvailables` is `0` (if your want `"All"` to be selected, you need to set the value of `model.SearchAvailables = -1;` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. (and use the strongly typed method - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchAvailables, Model.Availables)`)